# Linking select options with related data

Tags: angularjs

I've got an object `item` with a `department_id`, which refers to an array of objects `departments`. I'm trying to create a `select` in the form so that I can select the `department` and assign the correct `id` to `item.department_id`. So far, I've got:

```
<p>{{ item.department_id }}</p>
<select name="department" class="form-control m-b">
    <option ng-repeat="department in departments">{{department.name}}</option>
</select>
```

This allows me to select the department, but I don't know how to link the `department.id` to the `item.department_id`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ng-model` to bind the value selected in the select box to the `item.department_id`

```html
<p>{{ item.department_id }}</p>
<select name="department" class="form-control m-b" ng-model="item.department_id">
    <option ng-repeat="department in departments" value="{{department.id}}">{{department.name}}</option>
</select>
```

You can also use `ng-options` instead of creating the `option` tags manually:

```html
<p>{{ item.department_id }}</p>
<select name="department" class="form-control m-b" ng-model="item.department_id" ng-options="dept.id for dept in departments"></select>
```